# AWS CLI Download Performance Far Faster than Boto3

Tags: python-3.x, performance, boto3, aws-cli, botocore

I'm attempting to download a significant number of small files from AWS S3 (50,000+) and I'm consistently noting that the AWS CLI `sync` command is dominating my solution written in boto3.  I've started looking through the AWS CLI source for ways my boto solution could improve, but beyond replicating the TransferManager and TransferConfig I don't see precisely what causes such a performance increase

For example, the sync command:

`aws s3 sync s3://my-bucket/folder/subfolder folder/subfolder`

For 50,000 small files takes around 111 seconds.  In fact, that's even after I've wrapped the `sync` in a `subprocess` run.  And my similar code in python takes nearly double that time (210 seconds):

```
import boto3
import botocore
from s3transfer.manager import TransferManager
from s3transfer.manager import TransferConfig

# can get list of files anyhow, list_objects_v2, etc
files = []

botocore_config = botocore.config.Config(max_pool_connections=10)
s3_client = boto3.client('s3', config=botocore_config)

transfer_config = TransferConfig(
   max_request_concurrency=10,
   max_request_queue_size = 1000,
   multipart_threshold = 8 * (1024 ** 2),
   multipart_chunksize = 8 * (1024 ** 2),
   max_bandwidth = None
)

transfer_config.max_in_memory_upload_chunks = 6
transfer_config.max_in_memory_download_chunks = 6

s3t = TransferManager(s3client, transfer_config)

start = time.time()

for file in files:
    s3t.download(bucket=bucket, key=file, fileobj=file, subscribers=None)

s3t.shutdown()

end = time.time()
benchmark = end - start
print(f's3transfer {benchmark}')
```

My question is, what am I missing to get this download more performant?  I see that the AWS cli is able to download files much faster despite relying on the same botocore low level module to make its requests.

Comment: Is the destination folder in sync always empty? otherwise, you aren't downloading all 50k files, just checking for deltas. Also, what happens if you just use s3 = boto3.client('s3')
s3.download_file('BUCKET_NAME', 'OBJECT_NAME', 'FILE_NAME') and skip s3transfer altogether. I've not used s3transfer, but have used multiprocess to speed up downloads of many small files. Maybe there's just more overhead using s3transfer???

Comment: what is `TransferManager`?

Comment: I make sure to clean the destination folder prior to runs.  The AWS CLI uses s3transfer to actually run `sync` commands, and other boto3 download examples I've seen indicate that boto3 sessions aren't thread safe, but the client's are.

Additionally, `TransferManager` is a class declared by boto3 (and a version is also declared as part of s3transfer) to supposedly help increase throughput